# Типизированный файл в делфи

Tags: delphi

Можно ли в типизированный файл добавлять  запись, одним из полей которого будет текстовый файл ?

Comment: имя файла в string[255] засунуть. да и се а имена файлов как имена временных файлов делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю никак не получится. Что-то мне подсказывает, что:

- в типизированном файле размер записи фиксирован (иначе seek не сработает);
- переменная "текстовый файл", думаю, будет ссылкой на область памяти и при записи на диск ничего полезного не запишется.